# how to hit Rest api which requires Oauth authentication through outside java code

Tags: java, rest, api, oauth

I am making a POST request to Rest api which initially requires user to login and is using oauth logon. I am doing all this with java code and acting as a client for the third party Rest apis.
I have created following code in java for this but everytime I make request I get internal server error . My major aim to get the cookie from the Login request so that I can use that in next subsequent calls .

code :

```
URL Loginurl = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) Loginurl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
        out.write(strLoginString);
        out.close();
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode==200)
        {
            cookie = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
            return cookie;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how OAuth works. I am assuming you are using OAuth2, there is no session in OAuth. Instead you have something called as Access Token (which you get after exchanging the Authorization token - which itself is obtained by successfully authenticating the resource owner with identity provider)

There are 4 parties involved in OAuth - Client, Resource Owner, Resource Provider, Resource server. To access a resource (api) you need the resource owner (user) to authenticate with the identity provider (oauth api). You are the client and you have to work with the OAuth server and users browser to get the authentication done. You should not try to act as a man in middle for user authenticating with the identity provider. Once identity provider has authenticated the user, it will redirect user back to your endpoint with an auth token which then you can exchange with access token to execute the actual api call.

I would suggest reading up OAuth on the site [Oauth.net](https://oauth.net/)